# What is the term to describe all the instructions that executed as a result of a particular instruction?

Tags: programming-practices, terminology, definition

What is the term to describe all the instructions that executed as a result of a particular instruction?

```
main(){
  if(a)
    call_a();
  else
    call_b();
}
func call_a(){
  //do_something
  //sleep...
  call_b();
}
```

I would like to describe all the statements that are executed as a result of calling call_a() until it returns to main by term (like code flow or code sequence). Is there a universally accepted or standard term for this?

Comment: @ downvoter care to tell how I can improve the question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science); though that refers specifically to branch instructions in machine language, the conceptual idea is the same.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)

Comment: I did not downvote you, but when asking something like this, I would avoid to assume implicitly that there *is* such a term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tracing (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)).

FYI, we typically use the terms *statements* and *expressions* for programming language constructs and to describe lines of code in high-level language programs; we typically use the term *instructions* to describe what the hardware machine operations are.

Another term is an *execution trace*, which would capture a flow of execution.  An execution trace could be a high-level trace of the programming language statements (and/or expressions) executed, or could be a low-level trace of the machine instructions executed, or an (interleaved) combination of both!  Either way the trace represents a sequence of statements and/or instructions executed.